# How to convert object properties string to integer in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, javascript-objects

I would like to know how to convert object properties string to integer in javascript.
I have a `obj`, which if has property value is number string convert to number in javascript

```js
var obj={
  ob1: {id: "21", width:"100",height:"100", name: "image1"},
  ob2: {id: "22", width:"300",height:"200", name: "image2"}
}


function convertIntObj (obj){
    Object.keys(obj).map(function(k) { 
            if(parseInt(obj[k])===NaN){
              return obj[k] 
            }
            else{
              return parseInt(obj[k]);
            }
        });
}

var result = convertIntObj(obj);

console.log(result)
```

Expected Output:

```
[
  {id: 21, width:100,height:100, name: "image1"},
  {id: 22, width:300,height:200, name: "image2"}
]
```

Comment: You don't have any `return` in `convertIntObj`, so the value of the function call is implicitly `undefined`

Comment: ... and `NaN` is not equal to anything, not even to itself. Also, you need to map the properties of `obj` individually, currently you're parsing the objects in `obj`, not their properties.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should do the work:

```js
var obj = {
  ob1: {
    id: "21",
    width: "100",
    height: "100",
    name: "image1"
  },
  ob2: {
    id: "22",
    width: "300",
    height: "200",
    name: "image2"
  }
}


function convertIntObj(obj) {
  const res = {}
  for (const key in obj) {
    res[key] = {};
    for (const prop in obj[key]) {
      const parsed = parseInt(obj[key][prop], 10);
      res[key][prop] = isNaN(parsed) ? obj[key][prop] : parsed;
    }
  }
  return res;
}

var result = convertIntObj(obj);

console.log('Object result', result)

var arrayResult = Object.values(result);

console.log('Array result', arrayResult)
```

Click "Run code snippet" so see the result

Comment: thanks for helping out, but expected output is array

Comment: `Object.values(result)` is the array you want. I've added 2 more lines to the snippet

Comment: This converted `2021-1` to `2021` which was not desired. I added more strict checking via regex for any non numeric character, don't parse, but I feel like my code is clunky. Is this what you'd expect from your function or perhaps you could take a look?

Comment: To be clear, I wouldn't want `2021-1` parsed at all, but kept as a string due to non numeric characters. I use this for parsing ints in JSON to use with array sorting after, and it worked for the fields I wanted, but then I noticed other fields which shouldn't have been converted, were also effected negatively.

Answer (score 0):

Iterating over Object.keys() twice. If the value corresponding to the key is a number then parseInt the value else set the default value which was present  earlier

```js
var obj = {
  ob1: { id: "21", width: "100", height: "100", name: "image1" },
  ob2: { id: "22", width: "300", height: "200", name: "image2" }
};

var res = {};

Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
  res[key] = {};
  Object.keys(obj[key]).forEach(temp => {
    res[key][temp] = !isNaN(obj[key][temp])
      ? parseInt(obj[key][temp], 10)
      : obj[key][temp];
  });
  return res;
});

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) methods to iterate over the key value pairs in your data and use [`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) and [`Number.isNaN()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN) methods to transform the values appropriately.

```js
const data = {
  ob1: {id: "21", width:"100",height:"100", name: "image1"},
  ob2: {id: "22", width:"300",height:"200", name: "image2"}
};

const result = Object.entries(data).reduce((r, [k, o]) => {
    r[k] = Object.entries(o).reduce((r, [k, v]) => {
        let _v = Number(v);
        if(!Number.isNaN(_v)) { v = _v; }
        return (r[k] = v, r);
    }, {});
    return r;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score -2):

Hi I would recommend you to use the JSON.stringify() method. It is used to convert object to string which is needed to send data over the web server. It converts the set of variables in the object to a JSON string:

```js
var objToStr = {
  siteName: "W3Docs",
  bookName: "Javascript",
  booksCount: 5
};
var myJSON = JSON.stringify(objToStr);
console.log(myJSON);
```

Also, you can use the The toString() method. It is also called when you need to convert the object into a string:

```js
var obj = {
  siteName: "W3Docs",
  bookName: "Javascript",
  booksCount: 5
};
function objToString(object) {
  var str = '';
  for (var k in object) {
    if (object.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
      str += k + '::' + object[k] + '\n';
```

This information is taken from this [source](https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/javascript/how-to-convert-object-to-string.html).

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question. Unless I'm mistaken, it does precisely the opposite of what the OP wants (which is interesting, but not particularly helpful)...